# Python arcade can't install with pip

Tags: python, pip, arcade

I just booted a fresh install of Windows 11 and have been setting up my environment. I have been installing the libraries I use often including arcade using pip, but have run into an error only for this library only (numpy, PyAutoGUI, matplotlib, etc. all work fine). When I run `pip install arcade` I get a long list of errors. because there are so many it is hard to figure out what the problem is. Some potential errors are: `Failed building wheel for pillow`, `Failed building wheel for pymunk`, `Failed to build pillow pymunk`, and `The headers or library files could not be found for zlib, a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.`. I have included the full output below if that is useful. The one thing I did try from looking online was to manually uninstall an reinstall pillow, bu that does not seem to have done any thing. Any ideas of what I can do?

```
>pip3 install arcade
Collecting arcade
  Using cached arcade-2.6.17-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.5 kB)
Collecting pyglet==2.0.dev23 (from arcade)
  Using cached pyglet-2.0.dev23-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.1 kB)
Collecting pillow~=9.3.0 (from arcade)
  Using cached Pillow-9.3.0.tar.gz (50.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pymunk~=6.4.0 (from arcade)
  Using cached pymunk-6.4.0.zip (7.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pytiled-parser==2.2.0 (from arcade)
  Using cached pytiled_parser-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.3 kB)
Collecting attrs>=18.2.0 (from pytiled-parser==2.2.0->arcade)
  Using cached attrs-23.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.5 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\program files\python312\lib\site-packages (from pytiled-parser==2.2.0->arcade) (4.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.15.0 in c:\program files\python312\lib\site-packages (from pymunk~=6.4.0->arcade) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\program files\python312\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.15.0->pymunk~=6.4.0->arcade) (2.21)
Using cached arcade-2.6.17-py3-none-any.whl (39.4 MB)
Using cached pyglet-2.0.dev23-py3-none-any.whl (965 kB)
Using cached pytiled_parser-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Using cached attrs-23.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pillow, pymunk
  Building wheel for pillow (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pillow (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [203 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FitsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_deprecate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\PIL
      running egg_info
      writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src\Pillow.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.c'
      warning: no files found matching '*.h'
      warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
      warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'renovate.json'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext


      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 995, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\normal\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 368, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 89, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 345, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "<string>", line 810, in build_extensions
      RequiredDependencyException: zlib

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 410, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 395, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\wills\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_1euq_em\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 1012, in <module>
      RequiredDependencyException:

      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


      <string>:45: RuntimeWarning: Pillow 9.3.0 does not support Python 3.12 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow
  Building wheel for pymunk (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pymunk (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [105 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\arbiter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\autogeometry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\bb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\body.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\collision_handler.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\constraints.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\contact_point_set.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\matplotlib_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\pygame_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\pyglet_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\pymunk_extension_build.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\query_info.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\shapes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\shape_filter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\space.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\space_debug_draw_options.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\transform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\vec2d.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\_callbacks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\_chipmunk_cffi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\_pickle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\_pyglet15_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\_types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\_typing_attr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      copying pymunk\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\tests
      copying pymunk\tests\doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\tests
      copying pymunk\tests\test_arbiter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\tests
      copying pymunk\tests\test_autogeometry.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\tests
      copying pymunk\tests\test_bb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\tests
      copying pymunk\tests\test_body.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\tests
      copying pymunk\tests\test_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\tests
      copying pymunk\tests\test_constraint.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\tests
      copying pymunk\tests\test_shape.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\tests
      copying pymunk\tests\test_shape_filter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\tests
      copying pymunk\tests\test_space.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\tests
      copying pymunk\tests\test_space_debug_draw_options.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\tests
      copying pymunk\tests\test_transform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\tests
      copying pymunk\tests\test_vec2d.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\tests
      copying pymunk\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\tests
      copying pymunk\tests\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\tests
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\arrows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\balls_and_lines.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\basic_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\bouncing_balls.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\box2d_pyramid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\box2d_vertical_stack.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\breakout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\camera.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\constraints.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\contact_and_no_flipy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\contact_with_friction.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\copy_and_pickle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\damped_rotary_spring_pointer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\deformable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\flipper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\index_video.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\matplotlib_util_demo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\newtons_cradle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\planet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\platformer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\playground.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\point_query.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\pygame_util_demo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\pyglet_util_demo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\shapes_for_draw_demos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\slide_and_pinjoint.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\spiderweb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\tank.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\threaded_space.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\using_sprites.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\using_sprites_pyglet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      copying pymunk\examples\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk\examples
      running egg_info
      writing pymunk.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to pymunk.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to pymunk.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to pymunk.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'pymunk.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\src\_build'
      warning: no files found matching '*.wav' under directory 'additional_examples'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'additional_examples\.ipynb_checkpoints'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'additional_examples\build'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'additional_examples\dist'
      no previously-included directories found matching '**\__pycache__'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'pymunk.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying pymunk\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pymunk
      running build_ext
      generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\\Release\\pymunk._chipmunk.c'
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
      building 'pymunk._chipmunk' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pymunk
Failed to build pillow pymunk
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pillow, pymunk, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Thanks.

Note: I am running a fresh install of python 3.12.2 on a AMD processor with NVIDIA GPU if any of that is helpful.

Comment: To just quote the error back at you: The headers or library files could not be found for zlib, a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source. Please see the install instructions at: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the reply, but as I mentioned in the question I did try to do this manual installation, but still got this same error.

Comment: You mention seeing it, you didn't go over the part where you installed the requirements and then reran everything. However, that should also be mostly irrelevant because `arcade` is open source _and_ claims that the installation "should just work", so if it doesn't: did you search for known issues (or filed a new one) about this over on https://github.com/pythonarcade/arcade? And then for debuggin purposes: are you installing this in a virtual environment, or globally? And have you tried `python -m pip install arcade` to make sure your main python version gets used if globally?

Comment: No I did not, I will look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found that arcade Latest Release was `Dec 31, 2022`

[image]

Looks like it it does not support `python 3.12` yet.

[image]

**You need to install `python 3.11` separately then install arcade.**

Comment: Thanks. For anyone else looking at this I decided to install pyenv to more easily manage installing the previous versions while also having an up to date version elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, it's a better option.